# How to apply write protection in TextArea for wildcards using JQuery?

Tags: jquery, textarea

Does anyone know a possibility to protect a string-wildcard from changing in a TextArea?

HTML:

```
<textarea name="mail_text" id="mail_text">
{salutation} {recipient},
thanks for your email.
Regards
{username}
</textarea>
```

I would like to catch when someone tries to change one of the wildcards: *{salutation}*,*{recipient}* and *{username}*

```
$("textarea").keyup(function() {
  var val = $(this).val();
  //protect the wildcards
});
```

Comment: why does it have to be all at the text area, can't you separate them?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't practically ‘protect’ part of a textarea. Naïvely you could try to block input keypresses when the cursor is inside a `{...}` pattern, but there are so many other ways it could be edited, eg. select range then delete/replace, cut/copy/paste, drag and drop...

It might be better simply to monitor the textarea's value, and show a warning underneath it when there's something about the value that's wrong, eg.:

```
<textarea id="mail_text">...</textarea>
<div id="mail_text_warning"></div>

<script type="text/javascript">
    function checkMailText() {
        var tokens= ['username', 'recipient', 'salutation'];
        var value= $('#mail_text').val();
        var problems= [];

        $.each(tokens, function() {
            if (value.split('{'+this+'}').length!==2)
                problems.push('Please ensure there is one and only one {'+this+'} token present in the text');
        });
        matches= value.match(/\{[^\}]*\}/g);
        if (matches!==null) {
            $.each(matches, function() {
                for (var i= tokens.length; i-->0;)
                    if ('{'+tokens[i]+'}'===this)
                        return;
                problems.push('Token '+this+' is not known');
            });
        }

        $('#mail_text_warning').text(problems.join('. '));
    }
    setInterval(checkMailText, 500);
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Make all easier.
Create two **textareas**: one with information where user can write ("thanks for your email. Regards." etc). And another one with wildcards or end results if it is possible. You can modify the second **textareas** immediately after user type (use *keydown* or *keyup* event).